# Git : pushed branch not accessible by other user over http

Tags: git

I've created a bared repo on a server accessible by http.
I've cloned the repo, create a branch, do some modifications, commit them and push them to my remote repo with
git push myrepo branchname

On the server, I see my branch when typing git branch -a
But on my local repo, I don't see this branch when typing 
git ls-remote --heads myrepo. 
Although I see my branch under refs/heads directory on the server
This branch is also invisible if I create another clone of this repo elsewhere.

there's no error on push command.

I don't know what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved my problem :
I only have to enter git update-server-info in the git repository on my server to be able to see new branches.